# Error while running docker run hello-world

Tags: docker

I am new to DOCKER. I am using Community Edition, stable version on Windows 10 64bit OS.

Docker is installed successfully and it is showing status as running. However when i try below command i get error :

C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker>docker run hello-world

**docker: error during connect: Post http://C:2375/Program%20Files/Docker/Docker/v1.27/containers/create: dial tcp: lookup C: getaddrinfow: No such host is known..
See 'docker run --help'.**

Docker version is
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker>docker --version

Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

can anyone please help?

Comment: See [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/dial-tcp-error/5f9db435-e0ac-4cc3-953b-0e0b241fa3d2). But let's be honest, linux is better.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go for docker tool box if it is for development purpose. I too faced few issues when i was trying to install docker on my Windows 10.

Before go for further investigation about your problem, i want you to check the following;

1. Make sure Virtualization enabled. you can check it in BIOS configuration.
2. In final completion wizard of docker window, you must check "Launch Docker" (it will check by default)
3. If you think you installed properly, you should able to see the docker icon in the status bar.

If all the above criteria's seems fine, you can run the hello-world program and could able to see the output from docker hub.

For more information on how to install docker tool box on you windows. you can refer the [docker tool box for windows](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#step-2-install-docker-toolbox)

If you still have any issues, please type the below command on your terminal and send the result

> "docker info"

Hope this will help for you!